# Fragment.instantiate fatal exception

Tags: java, android, list, android-fragments

I have the following code:

```
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercises_list);


    List<Fragment> fList = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, "All"));
```

which is a fatal exception. If i remove line `fList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, "All"));`, it's fine. So what's happening? I have no idea how to use fragments so I'm guessing my problem is a nooby one.

Comment: do you have Multiple fragments to add in List ?? & Are you using List for any adapter like ViewPager??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Fragment` is a nested inner class, make sure you have declared it to be a `public static class`. Likewise, make sure the `Fragment` is named `All`.

That being said, I hope you know what you are doing, because I can't imagine a scenario in which I would store a `Vector` of `Fragment`s. At the very least you should use an `ArrayList` instead.

Also, you should post the exact error message you are getting, along with the rest of your logcat output.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add Fragment class instance in fList then below code will help you.

```
fList.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Your-Fragment-Class-Name.class.getName()));
```